# Extracting span values from within a class, VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

After plenty of searching, I'm struggling to scrape the data from the HTML below using VBA. Specifically, I am trying to pull the values 'DATA ONE' and 'DATA THREE' from each class="_Xnb _QJ" in the HTML code below:

```
<div class="results">
  <div class="_s2 _wPc">
    <div class="_fW _QJ">
    <div class="_Xnb _QJ _Z9b">
    <div class="_Xnb _QJ">
    <div class="_Xnb _QJ">
    <div class="_Xnb _QJ">
      <a href="//Extracted URL//">
        <span class="_fbb">
          <img id="uid_3" //Extracted// >
        </span>
        <span class="_PHb">
          <span class="_MHb">DATA ONE</span>
        </span>
        <span class="_B6e">
          <span class="_x2">DATA TWO</span>
          <span class="_Fs"> DATA THREE </span>
```

I have been trying to use getElementsByClassName to get a collection of the "_Xnb _QJ" classes, and for each of these classes use getElementsByTagName to search for "_MHb" and "_FS". I can't pick out the children in numerical order as this changes between "_Xnb.." classes, but the data I require always has the same (_MHb/FS) class tag attached.

I am a complete novice to VBA/HTML so this code has largely been assembled by editing examples elsewhere on stackoverflow. I wonder whether the fact that the classes I require are within the "href" rather than directly below the _Xnb class is the reason I cannot pull the correct data?

Relevant part of my VBA code below - when I run it, the code seems to run fine but no data is collected.

```
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim DataOne As String
Dim DataThree As String
Dim QuestionList As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Question As IHTMLElement
Dim QuestionFields As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim QuestionField As IHTMLElement
RowNumber = 1

Set QuestionList = html.getElementsByClassName("_Xnb _QJ")

For Each Question In QuestionList
Set QuestionFields = Question.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")

For Each QuestionField In QuestionFields
If QuestionField.className = "_MHb" Then
DataOne= QuestionField.innerText
Cells(RowNumber, 1).Value = DataOne
End If

If QuestionField.className = "_Fs" Then
DataThree = QuestionField.innerText
Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value = DataThree
End If

Next QuestionField
RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
Next
Set html = Nothing
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: EDIT: Going through the code with F8 instead of just executing the whole Sub actually seems to work with the code written above....any thoughts why this may be happening?

Comment: Code above section displayed:
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Sub ImportData()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Cells.Clear
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "//URL HERE EXTRACTED//"
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to load ..."
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = ie.document
Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to research [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) - a standards-based query language for working with XML documents. You can also use this with HTML documents where they are well formed. It is a bit arcane, but super-useful, and also can be used in VBA.

Your example HTML looks a bit complex as you have multiple `<div>` tags with the same class. Also it isn't valid XML because of the `//Extracted//` in the `<img>` tag. Also, there were no closing tags in the example. Anyway, I've tidied it up in the code example below.

I've looked at your question, and interpret it like this:

> Extract any text from a `<span>` tag where it is of class `_MHb` or `Fs`; and where it is a descendant of a `<div>` tag of class `_Xnb _QJ`

If so, your XPath query can be constructed in three parts:

```
//div[@class='_Xnb _QJ']
```

Meaning - get any div tags with class of `_Xnb _QJ`.

```
(//div[@class='_Xnb _QJ'])[last()]
```

Meaning - just get the innermost item from the first set (remembering you have multiple nested `<div>` tags with same class).

```
(//div[@class='_Xnb _QJ'])[last()]//span[@class='_MHb' or @class='_Fs']
```

Meaning - filter the innermost `<div>` for `<span>` tags which have class of `_Mhb` or `_Fs`.

So, you can use XPath in VBA if you include the MSXML library (which I think you already have done). The code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strXml As String
    Dim objXml As New DOMDocument60
    Dim strXPath As String
    Dim objXmlNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objXmlNode As IXMLDOMNode

    'get the sample XML
    strXml = GetXml

    'load xml to document
    If Not objXml.LoadXML(strXml) Then
        Debug.Print "Not parsed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'apply XPath
    'first just let's get the last <div> tag of class _Xnb _QJ
    strXPath = "(//div[@class='_Xnb _QJ'])[last()]"
    'test that query
    Set objXmlNodeList = objXml.SelectNodes(strXPath)
    For Each objXmlNode In objXmlNodeList
        Debug.Print objXmlNode.XML
    Next objXmlNode

    'now lets append a filter to only get the <span> texts
    strXPath = strXPath & "//span[@class='_MHb' or @class='_Fs']"

    'get output nodes by applying query to xml
    Set objXmlNodeList = objXml.SelectNodes(strXPath)
    For Each objXmlNode In objXmlNodeList
        Debug.Print objXmlNode.Text
    Next objXmlNode

End Sub

Function GetXml() As String

    Dim strXml As String

    strXml = ""
    strXml = strXml & "<div class=""results"">"
    strXml = strXml & "  <div class=""_s2 _wPc"">"
    strXml = strXml & "    <div class=""_fW _QJ"">"
    strXml = strXml & "      <div class=""_Xnb _QJ _Z9b"">"
    strXml = strXml & "        <div class=""_Xnb _QJ"">"
    strXml = strXml & "          <div class=""_Xnb _QJ"">"
    strXml = strXml & "            <div class=""_Xnb _QJ"">"
    strXml = strXml & "              <a href=""//Extracted URL//"">"
    strXml = strXml & "                <span class=""_fbb"">"
    strXml = strXml & "                  <img id=""uid_3"" />"
    strXml = strXml & "                </span>"
    strXml = strXml & "                <span class=""_PHb"">"
    strXml = strXml & "                  <span class=""_MHb"">DATA ONE</span>"
    strXml = strXml & "                </span>"
    strXml = strXml & "                <span class=""_B6e"">"
    strXml = strXml & "                  <span class=""_x2"">DATA TWO</span>"
    strXml = strXml & "                  <span class=""_Fs""> DATA THREE </span>"
    strXml = strXml & "                </span>"
    strXml = strXml & "              </a>"
    strXml = strXml & "            </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "          </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "        </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "      </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "    </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "  </div>"
    strXml = strXml & "</div>"

    GetXml = strXml

End Function
```

Debug output looks like this:

```
<div class="_Xnb _QJ">
    <a href="//Extracted URL//">
        <span class="_fbb">
            <img id="uid_3"/>
        </span>
        <span class="_PHb">
            <span class="_MHb">DATA ONE</span>
        </span>
        <span class="_B6e">
            <span class="_x2">DATA TWO</span>
            <span class="_Fs"> DATA THREE </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
DATA ONE
DATA THREE
```

It all looks a bit complex - but you will be fine once you have a few tries at it.

Comment: Many thanks - will have a look at using this (looks like may take a few tries indeed!)